# Why doesn't ~= work on enums and strings?

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching

While I was trying to answer another question, I found out that this code doesn't work:

```
enum Response {
    case positive
    case negative
    case neutral
}

func ~=(pattern: Response, value: String) -> Bool {
    switch pattern {
    case .positive:
        return ["yep", "yes", "yay", "definitely", "ok", "correct"]
            .contains(value.lowercased())
    case .negative:
        return ["no", "nope", "nah", "definitely not", "no way"]
            .contains(value.lowercased())
    case .neutral:
        return ["meh", "don't know", "indifferent", "don't care"]
            .contains(value.lowercased())
    }
}

switch "yep" {
case Response.positive:
    print("That was a positive response")
case Response.negative:
    print("That was a negative response")
case Response.neutral:
    print("That was a neutral response")
default:
    print("Something else")
}
```

I was trying to use the `~=` operator to allow pattern matching between strings and the `Response` enum, so that I can classify strings as a positive, negative, or neutral response (to a prompt).

Yes, I *could* have written the string values I accept for each kind of response directly into the switch cases, like

```
case "yep", "yes", "yay", "definitely", "ok", "correct":
    print("That was a positive response")
```

But I think saying `case Response.positive` creates another layer of abstraction, and allows late binding. I can read the acceptable responses from a file, for example.

From my knowledge, the first code snippet should work. I've defined a `~=` operator. I've unambiguously stated the enum values in the switch cases. The documentation doesn't say `~=` is not allowed on enums. Even `print(Response.positive ~= "yep")` prints `true`. ***But*** the switch cases emit the error of:

> Enum case 'positive' is not a member of type 'String'

(Of course it's not! You dummy! :D)

Why does it not work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in the following notation. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
switch "yep" {
case .positive:
    print("That was a positive response")
case .negative:
    print("That was a negative response")
case .neutral:
    print("That was a neutral response")
default:
    print("Something else")
}
```

Comment: Huh... Interesting. I  thought the compiler would not be able to infer the enum type if I don't write `Response`. The compiler can be smart sometimes, I guess.